# function similar to VLookup but returns every value relevant

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having some trouble finding a function that will allow me to take a list of data and return all the values relevant to a reference cell. The idea of it works like a Vlookup except Vlookup only returns the first value it sees.

I have thought about using a pivot table and/or using filters on my list but I run into problems with those because of the complexity of the workbook.

This is essentially what my workbook would look like:

```
    A         B       C
 1 Pen      Blue     200
 2 Marker   Red      150
 3 Pen      Black    180
 4 Pen      Green    170
 5 Marker   Green    125
```

I am trying to find a funtion to return this:

```
    A       B       C
 1 Pen    Blue     200
 2 Pen    Black    180
 3 Pen    Green    170
```

All I need it to do is to recognize Column A's value as "Pen" and bring back the color with it in Column B. Column C I can then use a Vlookup to get.

**I feel like I am missing something to help someone understand and be able to help me but I can't pinpoint what it is... if you need something else as clarification let me know**

Comment: If you filter on Pen, what happens? Is it not exactly what you showed? If your workbook is complex (which doesn't seem to be the case) we would need to know how :)

Comment: You can use array formulas but you will have to cap the number of lines

Comment: @DavidGM What is returned is then used in a vlookup on a different sheet which is then used in a pivot table. The problem with a filter is that all it does is hide the other data. I can't use the vlookup in a different sheet without it recognizing all the data that the filter is simply hiding. Now you might be thinking, well the Vlookup will only return the value if it matches the criteria. The problem is that I don't have a criteria for it to match until the data is filtered through. The data I provided is a much simpler version of what I have. For example, rather than `Blue` it is a unique..

Comment: code such as `XYZ_WEB_AUTH_B0001`.... I hope this helps a bit more

Comment: @exussum that was my other thought but the list is constantly being maintained so I can't cap the number of lines

Comment: Are you willing to look into VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with an array formula.

First, fill the first column with numbers 1 to the number of "Pen" in your lookup range.

Then, enter the formula:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5="Pen",ROW($A$1:$A$5),""),$A11))
```

Where $A11 is the cell where you started your enumeration from the first step.

Then press ctrl+shift+enter to make it an array formula.

The "if" returns an array of row numbers where the cell value is "Pen" (which can obviously be changed to other values if needed). Then the small returns the nth smallest, which is why we need the first column to be numbers 1 to numbers of "Pen" in range. Then the index returns the result cell in the specified range for that row. Be careful, this formula assumes your table starts at A1 (as per your example), but can easily be ajusted if that's not the case.

You can then drag it to the right and down and the formula will adapt as long as you keep the $ in the same places they are now.

The output will look like (assuming you start at A11 like I did):

```
     A       B       C        D
 11  1      Pen    Blue     200
 12  2      Pen    Black    180
 13  3      Pen    Green    170
```

Comment: Do I have to know the number of "Pen" or can I put some number that is larger than what I would expect to have? I won't know the total number of "Pen" there is in a sheet.

Comment: You could put any number that you know is bigger. Or you could do a countif(range,"Pen") before and use the exact number. The function will return an error if you extend it to a number bigger than then number of "Pen" for the rows that are bigger, but that's about it. If you don't want to see the error, you could aloways add an iferror(formula,"") which will simply hide errors.

Comment: In fact, comboing using a larger number with the iferror and dynamic named ranges, the result could update itself automatically whenever you add new values to your source table.

Comment: I see how this suppose to work but one question. When you say fill the first column with the numbers 1 to the number of "Pen" do you mean to number the things that  are not labled pen too? or is there a way to automatically number them if they are "pen"?

Comment: You only need the numbers in your second table, not in your first (source) one. You could do the numbering in an other page if you want. And you don't need to only put numbers for the ones that have "Pen", the formula finds them for you.

Comment: You could skip this step completly and change $A11 to row(thiscell)-row(first cell in output table)+1, so for my output table, it woule be: row(B11)-row(B$11)+1 and then extend the formula.

Comment: okay I tried working from the example I gave you to follow how you did this and I get 0 in all the cells.

Comment: got it. Let me try it with my list now.

Comment: Did you remember to hit Ctrl+shit+enter after entering the formula? I just tried it to make sure, and if you have your data in A1:C5, enter 1-2-3 in A11-A12-A13, then enter the exact formula I gave you in B11, press F2 and the ctrl+shift+enter, and then drag it two columns to the right and three down, I get the exact output I gave you earlier.

Comment: yeah i figured out that i forgot to do the ctrl+shift+enter but when applying it my list, it occasionally pulls random pieces such as `Marker` or `0` (keep in mind marker and pen are not actually the data pieces). I have no idea why  `marker` would end up in the results though. There are 314 unique "Pen" inputs but it doesn't grab them all and it pulls a few random ones... I'll keep playing with it

Comment: That's pretty weird. Were you able to make it work with your example data? Are the 0s in your data or is the formula making them appear?

Comment: found out that when I expand it, there are 314 entries but not all of them say "Pen" instead some say "marker" or "crayon"

Comment: You mean In the formula?

Comment: formula is making them appear. I haven't got any 0. I got the example data to work just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85150/discussion-between-latch-and-that-newbie).

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the value in column a and b by
=A1&","&B1
For the first row (and just drop it down)
Then you can make a pivot with the calculated column
I added a comma so you can split this after words with data-> text to columns->delimited->comma-> finish

Answer (score 1):

Since you're OK with vba, you could place all the values you want in an array along with the other ones. I'll make a rudimentary one since I'm not sure how much data you have.

```
sub arrayFiller()
    dim i as integer
    dim MyArr() As string
    dim nbOfRows as long

    nbOfRows = Sheets("Sheet1").cells(SHEET.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Redim MyArr(nbOfRows  , 3) 'Enough rows for you

    for i = 1 to nbOfRows  'dynamic so it works even if you change the list size
        if Sheets("Sheet1").range("A" & i).Value = "Pen" Then 'Change Pen to a dynamic reference or something else
            MyArr(i - 1, 0) = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A" & i).Value
            MyArr(i - 1, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").range("B" & i).Value
            MyArr(i - 1, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").range("C" & i).Value
        end if
    next i

'Now to empty to sheet 2
    for i = 1 to Ubound(MyArr)
         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = MyArr(i - 1, 0)
         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = MyArr(i - 1, 1)
         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = MyArr(i - 1, 2)
    Next i
End sub
```

You array should be filled now. You can empty it wherever or consult the values right from the array for more manipulation.

Comment: quick question on this, if the original list (the first one in the example) is in `sheet 1` and the end result (the second one in the example) is `Sheet 2`, what should I be changing?

Comment: You write Sheets("Sheet1") where I wrote SHEET. The array will fill with sheet1's data. Right now it stays in the array, it doesn't go into sheet2. If you want it to display in sheet 2 i can edit the answer.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could. It makes sense why you did it that way. I should have changed the column headings to something else in my example but yes, same columns but in sheet 2.

Comment: I haven,t tested it. I trust it works but if you have trouble making it work let me know, I'll fix it.

Comment: I realized that I shouldn't be using VBA for this worksheet as this is not one that will be used by people who who understand advanced parts of excel should this workbook happen to break...

Comment: No problem, maintenance is important too, that's true!